# Sending data from Arduino to the server where arduino (sketch) acts as a client

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, sketch

I want to make simple client-server program where arduino behave as a client. For example I have a LED connected in arduino board that is controlled by a switch. With the switch I can turn off and on the LED. Now I want to send the status of that LED to another computer wirelessly (let's say within the Local network). That computer will act as a server and update the change as soon as the LED changes its status. I am not expecting any complete code, I just want to know how could it be done in general? May be some links can help me? Because this is my first time working with client-server in arduino sketch, I need some kind of guidelines. Thank you.

Comment: There are example client-server sketches included in the IDE. Did you look at those?

Comment: When you say "Local Network" - do you mean over Wifi ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple HC-05 module will give you a wireless bluetooth connection.  They're fairly simple to setup, and you can write data to them the same as one would the Arduino serial console.  Obviously they can read data too.

```
SoftwareSerial bt_serial(2, 3); // RX | TX
bt_serial.begin(9600);

[...]

if (led_state != last_led_state)
{
    if (led_state == HIGH)
        bt_serial.print("1");
    else
        bt_serial.print("0");
    last_led_state = led_state;
}
```

On the "server" side, a simple program reading the mapped bluetooth serial port would do the job.  For example, some python code:

```
import serial
import sys

serial_port = serial.Serial(port='COM8:', baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)

try:
    serial_port.open()
except:
    print("Failed to open port")
    sys.exit(2)

while (True):
    try:
        led_state = serial_port.read()
        if (led_state != 0):
            print("LED is on")
        else:
            print("LED is off")
    except:
        pass

serial_port.close()   # yes, it never gets here
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though I like Kingsley's answer I thought I'd add to this using Wi-Fi becuase you had mentioned LAN.

These two links should be enough to help you:
[WifiChatServer](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiChatServer)
and [C# Telnet Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19071/Quick-tool-A-minimalistic-Telnet-library)

Those links can sort of be dissected to fit your needs, but if you need some actual code just tell me.

Now I am aware that **the Arduino is acting as a server and the computer acts as a client**, but I believe this setup is better because it's easier to manipulate connecting to servers on the computer rather than on the arduino side.